# My service is not updating - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a `service` to hold all of my search parameters.  This way I can call my `$resource` from anywhere I need and the search parameters are always correct.  Here is the `service`

```
App.factory('filterService', function () {
  var FilterService = {
    actorId: '0001234',
    actionStatus: ['BUILDING', 'STARTED', 'SENT'],
    payer: null,
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0,
    sortBy: null,
    filterBy: null,
    actionType: ['EB', 'AUTH'],
    actorType: 'REQUESTING'
  };

  return FilterService;
});
```

So when I call the my REST service I can access the search criteria like this:

```
App.factory('encounterService', function ($resource, filterService) {
  return {
    resource: $resource('/internal/v2/encounters/:encounterId', {encounterId:'@encounterId'}, {
      search: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'RemoteUser': 'jhornsby',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        params: {
          actorType: filterService.actorType,
          actorId: filterService.actorId,
          actionStatus: filterService.actionStatus,
          actionType: filterService.actionType,
          limit: filterService.limit,
          offset: filterService.offset,
          payer: filterService.payer,
          filterBy: filterService.filterBy,
          sortBy: filterService.sortBy
        }
      };
    }
  });
```

So I then call my `search` like this:

```
encounterService.resource.search({}, function(data) {
  // do something with data
});
```

But when I update my `filterService`, from a `controller`, it doesn't update my `filterService'.  Here is an example of the`filterService` being updated:

```
$scope.ok = function() {
    // Access the filter items with this.model
    filterService.actorId = $scope.model.actorId;
    filterService.actionStatus = $scope.model.actionStatus;
    filterService.actionType = $scope.model.actionType;
    filterService.limit = $scope.model.limit;
  }
```

Anytime I call `search`, it is always using the defaults.  How do I can I turn my search params into an object like I am trying to do here?

Comment: Where's the code that "updates the filterService from a controller"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the return statement inside your `encounterService` only gets called once, when the module is initialised. The `params` field on the search object gets evaluated then and so the values that the `filterService` has at that point in time are the values the `params` field is stuck with. In order to get around this, you need a way to evaluate the params object each time you want to make a query. A simple way to do this would be to return a function that you can call to get the resource, rather than the resource itself.

e.g.

```
App.factory('encounterService', function ($resource, filterService) {
  return {
    getResource: function () {
      return $resource('/internal/v2/encounters/:encounterId', {encounterId:'@encounterId'}, {
        search: {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'RemoteUser': 'jhornsby',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          params: {
            actorType: filterService.actorType,
            actorId: filterService.actorId,
            actionStatus: filterService.actionStatus,
            actionType: filterService.actionType,
            limit: filterService.limit,
            offset: filterService.offset,
            payer: filterService.payer,
            filterBy: filterService.filterBy,
            sortBy: filterService.sortBy
          }
        }
      };
    }
 }});
```

Which you can then call like this:

```
encounterService.getResource().search({}, function(data) {
      // do something with data
});
```

Comment: I have never done that.  Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I already did. Maybe the word "closure" has thrown you off. One creates closures all the time when writing Javascript, you just need to be aware of it. Try [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0):

I would use `filterService` like OO object with getter ans setter. By this way will be easy to handle your service object and easy to understand the code after.

Something like:

```
App.factory('filterService', function () {
  this.FilterService = {
    actorId: '0001234',
    actionStatus: ['BUILDING', 'STARTED', 'SENT'],
    payer: null,
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0,
    sortBy: null,
    filterBy: null,
    actionType: ['EB', 'AUTH'],
    actorType: 'REQUESTING'
  };

   this.getFilterService(){
     return this.FilterService;
   }


  this.setFilterService(service){
    this.FilterService = service;
  }
});
```

Now from controller we can call set:

```
filterService.setFilterService(dummyService);
```

and call get:

```
$scope.theService = filterService.getFilterService();
```

Hope it will work,